# Quick regexp to get path

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract the full path to a file using regExp

`mydomain.com/path/to/file/myfile.html` -> `mydomain.com/path/to/file/`

`/mypath/file.txt` -> `/mypath/`

anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
"mydomain.com/path/to/file/myfile.html".replace(/[^\/]*$/, "")
"/path/file.txt".replace(/[^\/]*$/, "")
```

But you can also do it without regular expressions by splitting:

```
"mydomain.com/path/to/file/myfile.html".split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/")+"/"
"/path/file.txt".split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/")+"/"
```

Answer (score 6):

Should be faster without RegExp:

```
path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Examples:

```
var path = "mydomain.com/path/to/file/myfile.html";
path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
"mydomain.com/path/to/file/"

var path = "/mypath/file.txt";
path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
"/mypath/"

var path = "file.txt";
path.substr(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
""
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex should do:

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/)*
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var file="mydomain.com/path/to/file/myfile.html";    
var match=/^(.*?)[\w\d\.]+$/g.exec(file);
var path=match[1];
```