# JS: Most optimized way to remove a filename from a path in a string?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have strings formatted as follows:

`path/to/a/filename.txt`

Now I'd like to do some string manipulation which allows me to very efficiently remove the "filename.txt" part from this code. In other words, I want my string to become this:

`path/to/a/`

What's the most efficient way to do this? Currently I'm splitting the string and reconnecting the seperate elements except for the last one, but I get the feeling this is a really, REALLY inefficient way to do it. Here's my current, inefficient code:

```
res.getPath = function(file)
{
  var elem = file.split("/");
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < elem.length-1; i++)
    str += elem[i] + "/";
  return str;
}
```

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161511

Comment: `split` is actually very fast, but definitely not the *fastest* way...

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Use lastIndexOf() to find the position of the last slash and get the part before the slash with substring().

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

Comment: Note that this will return a string with the filename on URLs like this: `http://example.com/index.php?p=about/location` or `http://ex.co/#/14185`

Comment: This won't work with path in the form of `/www/test`

Comment: If I want to remove last two index, then what could I do? i.e; i need to remove both Branch/Index from http://localhost:2698/Branch/Index

Comment: looks like its a path to a file, not an URL

Answer (score 21):

If you're using Node.js:

```js
const path = require("path")
const removeFilePart = dirname => path.parse(dirname).dir

removeFilePart("/a/b/c/d.txt")
// Returns "/a/b/c"
```

Comment: What benefit does this have over simply using [`path.dirname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_dirname_path)?

Comment: @JakeHolzinger path.dirname parses files differently when no root path is provided: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/18655

Answer (score 10):

How about this:

```
"path/to/a/filename.txt".split("/").slice(0, -1).join("/")+"/"
```

Comment: this isn't efficient, you create an array, remove elements, recreate a string etc, it just looks kind of cool

Answer (score 7):

In node, you can use `path.dirname`

```
const path = require('path')

fullFilePath = '/some/given/path/to-a-file.txt' 

directoryPath = path.dirname(fullFilePath) 

console.log(directoryPath)       // ===> '/some/given/path'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
str = str.split('/')
str.pop()
str.join('/') + '/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDirname(pathname, separator) {
    var parts = pathname.split(separator);
    if (parts[parts.length - 1].indexOf('.') > -1) {
        return parts.slice(0, -1).join(separator)
    }
    return pathname;
}
```

Usage:

```
var dir = getDirname(url.parse(request.url).pathname, '/');
```

.

```
var dir = getDirname(path.join('foo', 'bar', 'text.txt'), path.sep);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function splitPath(path) {
  var dirPart, filePart;
  path.replace(/^(.*\/)?([^/]*)$/, function(_, dir, file) {
    dirPart = dir; filePart = file;
  });
  return { dirPart: dirPart, filePart: filePart };
}
```

there that's better

Comment: I'm using JS outside a browser, and it's giving me a "SyntaxError: unterminated character class ["

Answer (score 0):

If this is to process a filename from a file upload form, the HTML5 spec recommends the following code:

```
function extractFilename(path) {
  if (path.substr(0, 12) == "C:\\fakepath\\")
    return path.substr(12); // modern browser
  var x;
  x = path.lastIndexOf('/');
  if (x >= 0) // Unix-based path
    return path.substr(x+1);
  x = path.lastIndexOf('\\');
  if (x >= 0) // Windows-based path
    return path.substr(x+1);
  return path; // just the filename
}
```

Reference: <strike>http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#file-upload-state</strike>
           http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)

Answer (score 0):

`test/dir/lib/file- _09.ege.jpg` - **Will be to** - `test/dir/lib/`

`file- _09.ege.jpg` - **Will be to** - `file- _09.ege.jpg`

```
    console.log("test - "+getPath('test/dir/lib/file- _09.ege.jpg'));

    function getPath(path){
        path = path.match(/(^.*[\\\/]|^[^\\\/].*)/i);
        if(path != null){
            return path[0];
        }else{
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

```js
console.log("test - "+getPath('test/dir/lib/file- _09.ege.jpg'));

        function getPath(path){
            path = path.match(/(^.*[\\\/]|^[^\\\/].*)/i);
            if(path != null){
                return path[0];
            }else{
                return false;
            }            
        }
```