# I'd like to remove the filename from a path using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, path

Using Javascript I'd like to remove the filename from the end of a string (path+filename), leaving me just the directory path.

Would regular expressions be ideal? Or, is there a simpler means of doing this using the string object?

Thanks for any help!

----ANSWERED & EXPLAINED---

The purpose of this code was to open finder to a directory. The data I was able to extract included a filename - since I was only trying to open finder (mac) to the location, I needed to strip the filename. Here's what I ended up with:

```
var theLayer = app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers[0];
//get the full path to the selected file
var theSpot = theLayer.source.file.fsName;
//strip filename from the path
var r = /[^\/]*$/;
var dirOnly = theSpot.replace(r, '');
//use 'system' to open via shell in finder
popen = "open"
var runit = system.callSystem(popen+" "+"\""+dirOnly+"\"");
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var urlstr = '/this/is/a/folder/aFile.txt';
var r = /[^\/]*$/;
urlstr.replace(r, ''); // '/this/is/a/folder/'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I really like regex.  Would you mind briefly explaining the regex portion?

Comment: Sure. The `[^\/]` means any non-slash (the `^` at the beginning in a `[]` negates it), and the `*` after it matches any number of characters. The `$` stands for the end of the string. So this regex will match any non-slash characters at the the end of the string.

Answer (score 12):

You haven't specified any sample inputs.

Assuming you always have a directory then the following will work.  It takes everything up to (but not including) the last slash.

```
test = "/var/log/apache2/log.txt";
console.log(test.substring(0, test.lastIndexOf("/")));
```

Comment: Use `slice` instead of `substr`: [JavaScript: Slice, Substring, or Substr?](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/substring-substr-slice-javascript/)

Answer (score 7):

You can use substring and indexOf:

```
var url = 'asdf/whatever/jpg.image';
url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

Comment: Use `slice` instead of `substr`: [JavaScript: Slice, Substring, or Substr?](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/substring-substr-slice-javascript/)

Comment: @Web_Designer There doesn't seem to be a significant difference in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question and has already been answered, however my requirement was to remove the file if it exists in the given path or don't do anything if its folder already.

The accepted answer's regex didn't work for me so I used this one:

```
let FilePathString = '/this/is/a/folder/aFile.txt';
let FolderPathString = '/this/is/a/folder/';
const RegexPattern = /[^\/](\w+\.\w+$)/i;
console.log(FilePathString.replace(RegexPattern, '')); // '/this/is/a/folder/'
console.log(FolderPathString.replace(RegexPattern, '')); // '/this/is/a/folder/'
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58533864/1366033), if you're using **node.js** (fair assumption if you're dealing with file paths) - you can use the [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module, call [`path.parse`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path), and retrieve the directory name with `dir` like this:

```js
const path = require("path")

let myPath = "folder/path/file.txt"
let myDir = path.parse(myPath).dir

console.log(myDir) // "folder/path"
```

This should be the most robust way to manage and parse file paths across different environments.