# Get base url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a url http://xyz.in/pqr/v/index.php and I want to get only http://xyz.in/pqr/v/ so how can I remove index.php from url.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JS: Most optimized way to remove a filename from a path in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187256/js-most-optimized-way-to-remove-a-filename-from-a-path-in-a-string)

Comment: `url.split('/').pop();`

Comment: @adeneo No. He doesnt want index.php. he wants the rest.

Comment: @RoyiNamir then use what's left on the array: `var arr = url.split('/); arr.pop(); arr = arr.join('/');`

Comment: @Kroltan dont tell it to me.

Comment: This is not an unusual problem, and is duplicated throughout the internet. It should be handled as such, not bickered over.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I realize pop() and shift() returns the popped of value, the point was to show an easy way to remove the last part of the URL, and I didn't bother posting `var arr = url.split('/'); arr.pop(); var url = arr.join('/')` as it seemed rather obvious to me.

Answer (score 6):

Try this.

```
  var host = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host+'/'
  alert(host);
```

if you want to avoid '/' at last, You can use this

```
var host2 = window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.host
```

SEE THIS [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HT7my/1/)

Comment: but how will you get **/pqr/v/** paths as mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way to get base url:

```
window.location.origin
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function

try with this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/tWEV9/1/)**

```
var getUrl  = "http://xyz.in/pqr/v/index.php";
var change = getUrl.replace('index.php','');
```

NOTE : If your ***'index.php'*** name is static

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function GetBaseUrl() {
    try {
        var url = location.href;

        var start = url.indexOf('//');
        if (start < 0)
            start = 0 
        else 
            start = start + 2;

        var end = url.indexOf('/', start);
        if (end < 0) end = url.length - start;

        var baseURL = url.substring(start, end);
        return baseURL;
    }
    catch (arg) {
        return null;


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var a='http://xyz.in/pqr/v/index.php';
alert(a.substring(0,a.lastIndexOf("/"))); //http://xyz.in/pqr/v"
```