# How to split filesystem path in Java?

Tags: java, string, path

If I have a string variable inside one class

```
MainActivity.selectedFilePath
```

which has a value like this

```
/sdcard/images/mr.32.png
```

and I want to print somewhere only the path up to that folder without the filename

```
/sdcard/images/
```

Comment: You can use regular expressions. For example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161511/quick-regexp-to-get-path

Comment: Since Java 11 there is a simple way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59753567/504807

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do:

```
File theFile = new File("/sdcard/images/mr.32.png");
String parent = theFile.getParent();
```

Or (less recommended)

```
String path = "/sdcard/images/mr.32.png";
String parent = path.replaceAll("^(.*)/.*?$","$1");
```

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/G72gV)

Answer (score 6):

```
    String string = "/sdcard/images/mr.32.png";
    int lastSlash = string.lastIndexOf("/");
    String result = string.substring(0, lastSlash);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

new File(MainActivity.selectedFilePath).getParent().getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 2):

Create a File object with that path and then use getPath method from [File Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
String realPath = "/sdcard/images/mr.32.png";
String myPath = realPath.substring(0, realPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String[] array = dir.split("[\\\\/]",-1) ;
String arrval="";

   for (int i=0 ;i<array.length;i++)
      {
        arrval=arrval+array[i];

      }
   System.out.println(arrval);
```

Comment: finally the regexp i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.lastIndexOf(int ch);` which gives you the last occurrense of the character ch

Answer (score 1):

try this :

`File file = new File("path");`

`parentPath = file.getParent();`

`parentDir = file.getParentFile();`

Answer (score 1):

- Files

If the Files actually exist on the box, you could wrap the Strings up in a File object and call [File.getParent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29).

- String.split()

If the files don't exist, you could use the String.split() function to split the String with "/" as delimiter. You could then drop the last String in the array and rebuild it. This approach is rather dirty though.

- Regular expressions

You could use regular expressions to replace the part after the last / with "".

Comment: The file does not need to exist on the file system to call getParent().

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Apache FileNameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html) in the Apache Commons IO library, and in particular [getFullPath()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getFullPath%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution -

```
 String selectedFilePath= "/sdcard/images/mr.32.png";
 selectedFilePath=selectedFilePath.substring(0,selectedFilePath.lastIndexOf("/"));
System.out.println(selectedFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 11:

```
String folderOnly = Path.of(MainActivity.selectedFilePath).getParent().toString();
```